# Returning data from ajax results in strange object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I know this question hast probably been asked a thousand times, but i cannot seem to find the answer. I want `result` to be the data returned from the ajax-request, which should be a json-data array (the result of `console.log(data)`).

```
  var result = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: dataPath,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      },
    error: function(){
      //alert("damn");  
      },
    data: {},
    aync: false
  });

  console.log(result);
```

However, `console.log(result);` will return some strange object, which I don't know how to handle. Why isn't `result` = `data` ?

Comment: what data do you get (example)? what data do you expect (example)? try `console.dir` instead of `concole.log`

Comment: @dystroy: Not a duplicate. That's about an asynchronous call, but the OP tries to do a synchronous call.

Comment: @Guffa You're right. But really the only acceptable answers are the ones that explain to OP why it's terribly bad to try to make a synchronous call.

Comment: OP, please note that `async: false` is now deprecated.

Comment: @dystroy: Doesn't look like that... http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Answer (score 1):

Typo.

Change this:

```
aync: false
```

to:

```
async: false
```

And the `ajax` method still returns the jqXHR object doing the request, not the result. Use the `data` parameter in the `success` call and store it somewhere.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think this isn't *really* helping OP. `aync: false` is a typo bug, but `async: false` is generally a conception bug.

Comment: @dystroy :It's *really* what's wrong with the code. Whether the method is good or not, that's another matter.

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove the `aync: false` from your code. It should be spelled `async: false` but you don't need it to achieve your goal and what it actually does is block the entire browser's user interface resulting in a terrible user experience. Remember that "A" in AJAX means **Asynchronous**.

The result of an `$.ajax()` call is a **promise** which is not the same as your data, but it can still be useful to get to your data. You just need to use it in a certain way.

Try changing:

```
 console.log(result);
```

to:

```
result.done(function (data) { 
    console.log(data);
});
```

or:

```
result.done(function (data) { 
    console.dir(data);
});
```

or even this might work - untested:

```
result.done(console.dir);
```

See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805) for a better explanation.

Comment: No, the result isn't a promise. The OP is trying to do a synchronous call, not an asynchronous call.

Comment: @Guffa In the case of an synchronous call, that promise will be already resolved, but it will still be a promise. Using this promise is marked as _deprecated_ in the docs, but apparently it is still the case.

Comment: Blocking the entire browser isn't a smart thing to do in this case. It's much better to use asynchronous call with a promise. My advice is to **NEVER** use **synchronous** AJAX (SJAX?) **EVER**.

Comment: @rsp: Even if it's not the best thing to do, that is what the op *is* trying to do.

Comment: @Guffa yes which is clearly the *wrong* way to do it and our responsibility is to help with better ways.

Comment: @rsp: Yes, but first you should point to what is wrong with *the code*, then you can talk about the limitations and drawbacks with the method.

Comment: @Guffa That's true that I should do that and incidentally that's what I did. :)

Comment: @rsp: Oh, you added that too.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `result` inside `success` function.

```
 var result;
  $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: dataPath,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          result = data;
          console.log(data)
          },
        error: function(){
          //alert("damn");  
          },
        data: {},
        async: false
      });

      console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `console.log(result)` returns a strange object, actually this strange object is known as `xhr (XMLHttpRequest)` object.

Since the call is `syncronous` because of `async: false` so it's easy to get the `returned data` like

```
var result = $.ajax({...}); // get the xhr object in to result
console.log(result.responseText); // xhr object has a "responseText" property
```

As because `result.responseText` will be available only after the request completes and there is no chance to execute this `console.log(result.responseText);` because of `async:false`, before the `request` completes because a `syncronous` ajax request hangs on everything before it finish the request.

In your `success` callback `data` will be an object because of `dataType: 'json'` but outside of `success` callback, i.e. `console.log(result.responseText);` will be only text so to use it as an object you have to convert it to an object using `$.parseJSON(result.responseText)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small spelling mistake aync: false should read async: false assuming of course that you require the request to run synchronously i.e. for the remainder of your code to wait for this result.

I think that the main issue here is that the result you are trying to output to the console is not being referenced by the ajax request.

It is entirely your choice how you reference the data returned by the ajax request, you chose the word data this could just as easily have been result or json_Data or return_Data or ....

Hence to send the result of the ajax request to the console I would suggest:

```
var result = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: dataPath,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result)
      },
    error: function(){
      //alert("damn");  
      },
    data: {},
    async: false
  });
```