# Nodejs + express promisse

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm having difficulty understanding how works promise, I tried to create promise with express, to query on mysql and get results. I read that it is not cool to make this synchronous. I'm trying to make a little game, this route is for the registration.

```
var lang = require('../lang.js');
var config  =  require('../config.js');
var fieldValidator = require('../libs/field_validator');
var microtime = require('microtime');
var crypto = require('crypto');
//Presets
var lang = new lang();
var rlang = lang.returnMessage;
var fieldValidator = new fieldValidator();
var moment = require('moment');

module.exports = function(app, my){
    //Primeiro os registros
    /// Account Register
    ////
    var check_username = function(username){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            my.query('SELECT username FROM 4h_users WHERE ?', username, function (error, result, fields) {
                if (error) {
                    reject({"status": "error", "code":10 ,"message": rlang(lang, 10)});
                }else{
                    if(result.lenght > 0){
                        reject({"status": "error", "code":10 ,"message": rlang(lang, 10)});
                    }else{
                        resolve(true);
                    }
                };
            });
        });
    }
    check_username().then(function(id_user) {
      console.log(value);
    }, function(reason) {
      res.
    });


    app.post('/api/usuario/registrar', function(req, res){
        if(!req.body.lang){
            return res.send({"status": "error", "code":1 ,"message": 'Blank Language'});
        }else{
            var lang = req.body.lang;
        }
        if(!req.body.recode){
            return res.send({"status": "error", "code":4 ,"message": rlang(lang, 4)});
        }else if(!req.body.username){
            return res.send({"status": "error", "code":1 ,"message": rlang(lang, 1)});
        }else if(!req.body.password){
            return res.send({"status": "error", "code":3 ,"message": rlang(lang, 3)});
        }else if(!req.body.email){
            return res.send({"status": "error", "code":5 ,"message": rlang(lang, 5)});
        }else if(req.body.reemail != req.body.email){
            return res.send({"status": "error", "code":6 ,"message": rlang(lang, 6)});
        }

        my.query('SELECT email FROM 4h_users WHERE ?', req.body.email, function (error, result, fields) {
            if (error) {
                return res.send({"status": "error", "code":10 ,"message": rlang(lang, 10)});
            }else{
                return res.send({"status": "error", "code":13 ,"message": rlang(lang, 13)});
            };
        });

        if(!fieldValidator.username.isValid(req.body.username)){
           return res.send({"status": "error", "code":9 ,"message": rlang(lang, 9)});
        }else if(!fieldValidator.email.isValid(req.body.email)){
           return res.send({"status": "error", "code":7 ,"message": rlang(lang, 7)});
        }else if(!fieldValidator.password.isValid(req.body.password)){
           return res.send({"status": "error", "code":8 ,"message": rlang(lang, 8)});
        }

        var ip = generate_ip();
        var salt = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(microtime.now()+req.body.username).digest("hex");
        var password = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(salt+req.body.password).digest("hex");

        var user = {
            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: password,
            salt: salt,
            token_expiration: microtime.now(),
            money: config.default_bonus.money,
            hcoins: config.default_bonus.hcoins,
            register_date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
            token: crypto.createHash('sha256').update(microtime.now()+req.body.username).digest("hex"),
            token_expiration: microtime.now()+config.expiration.login,
            offline_mode_expiration: 0
        };

        //Check if machine ip exists and generate another one
        check_ip_status(my, ip);

        // Time to mysql

        //Add new user to mysql
        my.query('INSERT INTO 4h_users SET ?', user, function (error, result, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return res.send({"status": "error", "code":10 ,"message": rlang(lang, 10)});
            }else{
                var machine = {
                    ip: ip,
                    id_user: result.insertId
                };
                //Add new machine to mysql
                my.query('INSERT INTO 4h_machines SET ?', machine, function (error, result, fields) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        return res.send({"status": "error", "code":10 ,"message": rlang(lang, 10)});
                    }else{
                        return res.send({"status": "success", "code":11 ,"message": rlang(lang, 11)});
                    };
                });
            };
        });
    });
}


function generate_ip(){
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 254) + 1) + "." + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 254) + 1) + "." + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 254) + 1) + "." + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 254) + 1);
}
function check_ip_status(my, ip){
    my.query('SELECT ip FROM 4h_machines WHERE ?', ip, function (error, result, fields) {
        if (error) {
            return res.send({"status": "error", "code":10 ,"message": rlang(lang, 10)});
        }else{
            if(result.lenght > 0){
                ip = generate_ip();
                check_ip_status(ip);
            }
        };

    });
}
//id_user, username, salt, password, email, avatar_url, 4h_coins, money, last_login, register_date, token, token_expiration, reputation, actions, email_verify, modo_offline_expiration
```

and if you have another tips for this code please tell me, i'm learning and any help be very useful to me
thanks

Comment: You should always wait for MySQL query results. So divide the code into pieces. Please read this page; https://blog.risingstack.com/asynchronous-javascript/

Comment: You appear to be trying to send multiple responses to this request.  When you do `my.query()` and then have an if/else in the response, you send a response with `res.send()` for all possible results there.  Then, you also have `res.send()` later in your function.  You can't do that.  You send one response only per request.  So, the logic flow here is just wrong.  In addition, you need to continue your processing inside the `my.query()` callback, not after it.

Answer (score 2):

> if you have another tips for this code please tell me, i'm learning and any help be very useful to me thanks

This is a very general question which can be summarized as: How can I learn about promises. There are *a lot* of questions and answers on Stack Overflow about promises that I can recommend:

- [promise call separate from promise-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720512/promise-call-separate-from-promise-resolution/40721397#40721397)
- [Q Promise delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287845/node-q-promise-delay/41287978#41287978)
- [Return Promise result instead of Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719024/return-promise-result-instead-of-promise-in-nodejs/41719314#41719314)
- [Exporting module from promise result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279796/exporting-node-module-from-promise-result/41279904#41279904)
- [What is wrong with promise resolving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284107/what-is-wrong-with-promise-resolving/41284674#41284674)
- [Return value in function from a promise block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785769/return-value-in-function-from-a-promise-block/40785901#40785901)
- [How can i return status inside the promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764599/how-can-i-return-status-inside-the-promise/39765591#39765591)
- [Should I refrain from handling Promise rejection asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920179/should-i-refrain-from-handling-promise-rejection-asynchronously/40921505#40921505)
- [Is the deferred/promise concept in JavaScript a new one or is it a traditional part of functional programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845328/is-the-deferred-promise-concept-in-javascript-a-new-one-or-is-it-a-traditional-p/11845403#11845403)
- [How can I chain these functions together with promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659829/how-can-i-chain-these-functions-together-with-promises/39660257#39660257)
- [Promise.all in JavaScript: How to get resolve value for all promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643386/promise-all-in-javascript-how-to-get-resolve-value-for-all-promises/40643489#40643489)
- [Why Promise.all is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308568/promise-all-in-node-is-undefined/41308699#41308699)
- [function will return null from javascript post/get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071337/function-will-return-null-from-javascript-post-get/42072290#42072290)
- [Use cancel() inside a then-chain created by promisifyAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515775/use-cancel-inside-a-then-chain-created-by-promisifyall/40515981#40515981)
- [Why is it possible to pass in a non-function parameter to Promise.then() without causing an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094764/why-is-it-possible-to-pass-in-a-non-function-parameter-to-promise-then-without/42094874#42094874)
- [Implement promises pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245867/implement-promises-pattern/15246695#15246695)
- [Promises and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985066/nodejs-promises-and-performance/37986778#37986778)
- [Trouble scraping two URLs with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305539/nodejs-trouble-scraping-two-urls-with-promises/41305907#41305907)
- [http.request not returning data even after specifying return on the 'end' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744595/nodejs-http-request-not-returning-data-even-after-specifying-return-on-the-end/41744917#41744917)
- [async.each not iterating when using promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567353/async-each-not-iterating-when-using-promises/41567712#41567712)
- [jQuery jqXHR - cancel chained calls, trigger error chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111695/jquery-jqxhr-cancel-chained-calls-trigger-error-chain/5112734#5112734)
- [Correct way of handling promisses and server response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661064/correct-way-of-handling-promisses-and-server-response/39661503#39661503)
- [Return a value from a function call before completing all operations within the function itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081417/could-node-feasibly-return-a-value-from-a-function-call-before-completing-all-op/42088840#42088840)
- [Resolving a setTimeout inside API endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729806/resolving-a-settimeout-inside-api-endpoint/40730062#40730062)
- [Async wait for a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741374/async-wait-for-a-function/40741587#40741587)
- [JavaScript function that returns AJAX call data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150571/javascript-function-that-returns-ajax-call-data/5150650#5150650)
- [try/catch blocks with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884153/try-catch-blocks-with-async-await/40886720#40886720)
- [jQuery Deferred not calling the resolve/done callbacks in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159304/jquery-deferred-not-calling-the-resolve-done-callbacks-in-order/5159765#5159765)
- [Returning data from ajax results in strange object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660596/returning-data-from-ajax-results-in-strange-object/12660711#12660711)
- [javascript - Why is there a spec for sync and async modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523091/javascript-why-is-there-a-spec-for-sync-and-async-modules/40525271#40525271)
- [Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805)