# returning data in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, factory

I have two files in my application,
DesignFactory.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
var designtokenfile = require ('./designtokenfile');
var designtokendb = require ('./designtokendb');
var TYPE=process.env.TYPE;
var DesignFactory={};
DesignFactory.storeDesign = function(TYPE) {
if (TYPE == 'file') {
  var data=design.designtokenfile.load();
  console.log(data);

} else if (TYPE == 'db') {
  return designtokendb;
}
};

module.exports.design=DesignFactory;
```

now, I have another designtokenfile.js file,
 designtokenfile.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var load = function() {
fs.readFile('output.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {

  return data;
 if (err) {
   return console.log(err);
 }
    });

 };

 module.exports.load=load;
```

So my problem is am not able get data returned from load method. when I print data inside storeDesign method returned from load function, it displays undefined.
but I want contents of output.txt inside storeDesign method.
Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: use the callbacks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var load = function() {
  fs.readFile('output.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    return data;
     if (err) {
       return console.log(err);
     }
  });
};
```

which has no way of working because the `if` after the `return` would never be reached, use this:

```
var load = function(cb) {
  fs.readFile('output.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
     if (err) {
       console.log(err);
       return cb(err);
     }
     cb(null, data);
  });
};
```

and use it like this:

```
load((err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // handle success
  }
});
```

Or use this:

```
var load = function(cb) {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
     fs.readFile('output.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         reject(err);
       }
       resolve(data);
     });
  });
};
```

and use it like this:

```
load().then(data => {
    // handle success
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error
});
```

In other words, you cannot return a value from a callback to asynchronous function. Your function either needs to tak a callback or return a promise.

You need to reed more about asynchronous nature of Node, about promises and callbacks. There are *a lot* of questions and answers on Stack Overflow that I can recommend:

- [promise call separate from promise-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720512/promise-call-separate-from-promise-resolution/40721397#40721397)
- [Q Promise delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287845/node-q-promise-delay/41287978#41287978)
- [Return Promise result instead of Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719024/return-promise-result-instead-of-promise-in-nodejs/41719314#41719314)
- [Exporting module from promise result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279796/exporting-node-module-from-promise-result/41279904#41279904)
- [What is wrong with promise resolving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284107/what-is-wrong-with-promise-resolving/41284674#41284674)
- [Return value in function from a promise block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785769/return-value-in-function-from-a-promise-block/40785901#40785901)
- [How can i return status inside the promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764599/how-can-i-return-status-inside-the-promise/39765591#39765591)
- [Should I refrain from handling Promise rejection asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920179/should-i-refrain-from-handling-promise-rejection-asynchronously/40921505#40921505)
- [Is the deferred/promise concept in JavaScript a new one or is it a traditional part of functional programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845328/is-the-deferred-promise-concept-in-javascript-a-new-one-or-is-it-a-traditional-p/11845403#11845403)
- [How can I chain these functions together with promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659829/how-can-i-chain-these-functions-together-with-promises/39660257#39660257)
- [Promise.all in JavaScript: How to get resolve value for all promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643386/promise-all-in-javascript-how-to-get-resolve-value-for-all-promises/40643489#40643489)
- [Why Promise.all is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308568/promise-all-in-node-is-undefined/41308699#41308699)
- [function will return null from javascript post/get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071337/function-will-return-null-from-javascript-post-get/42072290#42072290)
- [Use cancel() inside a then-chain created by promisifyAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515775/use-cancel-inside-a-then-chain-created-by-promisifyall/40515981#40515981)
- [Why is it possible to pass in a non-function parameter to Promise.then() without causing an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094764/why-is-it-possible-to-pass-in-a-non-function-parameter-to-promise-then-without/42094874#42094874)
- [Implement promises pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245867/implement-promises-pattern/15246695#15246695)
- [Promises and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985066/nodejs-promises-and-performance/37986778#37986778)
- [Trouble scraping two URLs with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305539/nodejs-trouble-scraping-two-urls-with-promises/41305907#41305907)
- [http.request not returning data even after specifying return on the 'end' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744595/nodejs-http-request-not-returning-data-even-after-specifying-return-on-the-end/41744917#41744917)
- [async.each not iterating when using promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567353/async-each-not-iterating-when-using-promises/41567712#41567712)
- [jQuery jqXHR - cancel chained calls, trigger error chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111695/jquery-jqxhr-cancel-chained-calls-trigger-error-chain/5112734#5112734)
- [Correct way of handling promisses and server response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661064/correct-way-of-handling-promisses-and-server-response/39661503#39661503)
- [Return a value from a function call before completing all operations within the function itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081417/could-node-feasibly-return-a-value-from-a-function-call-before-completing-all-op/42088840#42088840)
- [Resolving a setTimeout inside API endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729806/resolving-a-settimeout-inside-api-endpoint/40730062#40730062)
- [Async wait for a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741374/async-wait-for-a-function/40741587#40741587)
- [JavaScript function that returns AJAX call data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150571/javascript-function-that-returns-ajax-call-data/5150650#5150650)
- [try/catch blocks with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884153/try-catch-blocks-with-async-await/40886720#40886720)
- [jQuery Deferred not calling the resolve/done callbacks in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159304/jquery-deferred-not-calling-the-resolve-done-callbacks-in-order/5159765#5159765)
- [Returning data from ajax results in strange object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660596/returning-data-from-ajax-results-in-strange-object/12660711#12660711)
- [javascript - Why is there a spec for sync and async modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523091/javascript-why-is-there-a-spec-for-sync-and-async-modules/40525271#40525271)
- [Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805)

Answer (score 0):

[`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) ist asynchrone so you need to pass a callback function or use [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined` because of asynchronous nature.. Try for the following code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var load = function(callback) {
fs.readFile('output.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {

  //return data;
   callback(null, data);
 if (err) {
   callback("error", null);
 }
    });

 };

 module.exports.load=load;

var fs = require('fs');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
var designtokenfile = require ('./designtokenfile');
var designtokendb = require ('./designtokendb');
var TYPE=process.env.TYPE;
var DesignFactory={};
DesignFactory.storeDesign = function(TYPE) {
if (TYPE == 'file') {
  var data=design.designtokenfile.load(function(err, res){
   if(err){
   } else {
    console.log(data);
   }
}); 

} else if (TYPE == 'db') {
  return designtokendb;
}
};

module.exports.design=DesignFactory;
```